# VB.NET Game Cooldown

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a game, and I had a problem: I don't know how to put cooldown to skills.
Example:
"Bob deals 25 damage to a target and stun their offensive skills until a new friendly skill is used."
Ok, so is now the Bab turn.
Bab uses a friendly skill and end turn.
Bob will can attack 25 damage and stunning, every turn, making Bab offensive skills stuned.

So, how can I do to Bob's 25 damage attack have a 1 turn cooldown?

**There is the code:**

Public Class Form1

```
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wparam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    Dim n As New Random
    If n.Next(100) <= 50 Then
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 0
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
    Else
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 0
        WaterControl.Visible = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RESET_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RESET.Click
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    ProgressBar2.Value = 100
    Label1.Text = ""
    Label2.Text = ""
    Label3.Text = ""
    Label4.Text = ""
    Label5.Text = ""
    Label6.Text = ""

    KyuubiChakra.Visible = 1
    KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 1
    DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 1
    WaterControl.Visible = 1

    Dim t As New Random
    If t.Next(100) <= 50 Then
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 0
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
    Else
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 0
        WaterControl.Visible = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NidaimeHokage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NidaimeHokage.Click
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    Label1.Text = "Nidaime Hokage"
    Label2.Text = "The second Hokage from Konoha."
    Label3.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiNaruto_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiNaruto.Click
    Label4.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    Label4.Text = "Kyuubi Naruto"
    Label5.Text = "Enraged Naruto."
    Label6.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub DarkGenjutsu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DarkGenjutsu.Click
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label1.Text = "Dark Genjutsu"
    Label2.Text = "Nidaime Hokage steals 35 health points from a target."
    Label3.Text = "This skill can only be used when Nidaime has 35 or less health."
End Sub

Private Sub WaterControl_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WaterControl.Click
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label1.Text = "Water Control"
    Label2.Text = "Nidaime Hokage deals 25 damage to a target and"
    Label3.Text = "stun offensive skills until that target use a friendly skill."
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiChakra_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiChakra.Click
    Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label4.Text = "Rage Chakra"
    Label5.Text = "Kyuubi Naruto deals 10 damage to"
    Label6.Text = "a target and heals 15 health points."
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiRasengan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiRasengan.Click
    Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label4.Text = "Kyuubi Rasengan"
    Label5.Text = "Kyuubi Naruto deals 55 damage to"
    Label6.Text = "a target and loses 20 health points."
End Sub

Private Sub DarkGenjutsu_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DarkGenjutsu.DoubleClick
    If ProgressBar1.Value <= 35 Then
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 0
        WaterControl.Visible = 0
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 1
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 1
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value - 35 < ProgressBar2.Minimum And ProgressBar1.Value <= 35 Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Minimum
    ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value <= 35 Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value - 35
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value <= 35 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 35
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Minimum Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nidaime Wins!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WaterControl_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WaterControl.DoubleClick
    If ProgressBar2.Value - 25 < ProgressBar2.Minimum Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Minimum
    Else
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value - 25
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 0
        WaterControl.Visible = 0
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 1
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nidaime Wins!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiChakra_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiChakra.DoubleClick
    If ProgressBar1.Value - 10 < ProgressBar1.Minimum Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value - 10
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 0
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 1
        WaterControl.Visible = 1
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Naruto Wins!")
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value + 15 > ProgressBar2.Maximum Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Maximum
    Else
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value + 15
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiRasengan_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiRasengan.DoubleClick
    If ProgressBar1.Value - 55 < ProgressBar1.Minimum Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value - 55
        KyuubiChakra.Visible = 0
        KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
        DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 1
        WaterControl.Visible = 1
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value - 20 < ProgressBar2.Minimum Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Minimum
    Else
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value - 20
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum Then
        MessageBox.Show("Naruto Wins!")
    ElseIf ProgressBar2.Value <= ProgressBar2.Minimum Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nidaime Wins!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DarkGenjutsuSTUN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DarkGenjutsuSTUN.Click
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label1.Text = "Dark Genjutsu"
    Label2.Text = "Nidaime Hokage steals 35 health points from a target."
    Label3.Text = "This skill only can be used when Nidaime has 35 or less health."
End Sub

Private Sub WaterControlSTUN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WaterControlSTUN.Click
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label1.Text = "Water Control"
    Label2.Text = "Nidaime Hokage deals 25 damage to a target and"
    Label3.Text = "stun offensive skills until that target use a friendly skill."
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiChakraSTUN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiChakraSTUN.Click
    Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label4.Text = "Rage Chakra"
    Label5.Text = "Kyuubi Naruto deals 10 damage to"
    Label6.Text = "a target and heals 15 health points."
End Sub

Private Sub KyuubiRasenganSTUN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KyuubiRasenganSTUN.Click
    Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Label4.Text = "Kyuubi Rasengan"
    Label5.Text = "Kyuubi Naruto deals 55 damage to"
    Label6.Text = "a target and loses 20 health points."
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Increment(0)
    ProgressBar2.Increment(0)
    Label7.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
    Label8.Text = ProgressBar2.Value
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= 65 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 1, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 65 And ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 3, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If

    If ProgressBar2.Value >= 65 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 1, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value < 65 And ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 3, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value < 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pass1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Pass1.Click
    DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 0
    WaterControl.Visible = 0
    KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 1
    KyuubiChakra.Visible = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Pass2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Pass2.Click
    DarkGenjutsu.Visible = 1
    WaterControl.Visible = 1
    KyuubiRasengan.Visible = 0
    KyuubiChakra.Visible = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(0)
    ProgressBar2.Increment(0)
    Label7.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
    Label8.Text = ProgressBar2.Value
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= 65 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 1, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 65 And ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 3, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If

    If ProgressBar2.Value >= 65 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 1, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value < 65 And ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 3, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
    If ProgressBar2.Value < 35 Then
        SendMessage(ProgressBar2.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Look --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbT4F.png

Comment: This is a bad question.  You've provided no code to show what you've tried.  You also haven't explained how turns or timers are implemented as is.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to include what you have tried, sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a game turn variable that increments each turn. e.g. TurnCounter
Create a class for your skills that includes a property that indicates when it is next available. e.g. Power.CooldownUntil
Set the property when it is disabled and check it when they attempt to use it.

For example:

```
' to disable a power for 2 turns the code might look like  
Player1.SpecialPower.CooldownUntil = TurnCounter + 2


' to test a power to see if it can be used:
If Player1.SpecialPower.CooldownUntil < TurnCounter Then
    ' use the power
Else
    ' don't use the power
End If
```

I'm assuming you know how to create classes and properties. If you don't, I'm sorry but I can't help you.

Comment: You don't even need to track the current turn.  Just have a cooldown property and if it's > 0, the ability is on cooldown, it can't be used.  Then at the beginning of each turn, if it's > 0, decrement it by 1.

Comment: You can explain how can I do this?

Comment: @nhgrif: That'd work well for one cooldown.  If you have multiple independent cooldowns, though, you then have to mess with a bunch of counters.   Saying "can't use until this time/turn/etc" scales better; then you have one counter to bother with.

Comment: @cHao can you help me with this?

Comment: What part?  This answer pretty much has the info you need...unless you don't know how to create a class.  If that's the problem, then a Q/A forum will never be as much help as a good book or tutorial web site on VB.net.

Comment: Yeah.. I really don't know how to create a class. Anyway, thank you for help.